# Can Blender generate a scene based off of a text file?

Tags: python, blender, render-to-texture

I have written a program in Python that generates a 10,000 tile coordinate plane with each tile having characteristics such as texture, temperature, elevation etc. I am doing this for a project and thought a much better way to show this part of the project would be to show a 3d rendering of it and the best program i know for that is Blender. I know scripts can be written in Python for Blender but I'm not sure how blender can generate things based off of a text file that my Python program writes to. If anyone knows if and how Blender can generate things from a text file or any other way i could have my Python program write to Blender would be excellent!

~ Thanks

Comment: You should be more specific... I think the Python API changed in the 2.5/2.6 versions of Blender (and couldn't find them), but there are still the 2.4x docs http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Extensions/Python

Comment: Would you like me to be more specific about my version of Python, Blender both, or what I'm trying to do?

Comment: About what you're trying to do... BTW, I think I found the latest API docs: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_release/

Comment: Thanks for the docs. To be more specific a bout why i am trying to do:

Comment: What i am trying to do is have blender take data out of a text file from my Python program or have the program run in blender (If that is possible) and create a grid based on that data. i.e. In the file or some other place will be data on tiles and information about them like tile 1 has dirt. I want Blender to grab that data and create a plane with that texture on it. is this possible? and will those docs have all the information i need to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make a Python script for that - that would read your text file and use blender API internally to create the tiles and the scene. Blender can only render files if it does have programs (plug-ins) that do that. Actually most file-formats can be read by blender just due to plug-ins implemented in Python that are shipped with the program.

Alternatively, you can adapt your program that generates the scene to be able to, beyond generating the text file, to draw it inside blender using its API instead. This approach might be easier than writing a separate logic to parse your own file.

If your script is Python2.x you will have to use blender 2.49 - as Blender 2.5 and newer versions use Python 3 for scripting.